# Designing an optional many-to-many relationship with access restrictions in Spring Data JPA / Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to design a simple discount code app, that allows users to keep track of their use of discount codes. I already have an existing "public" list of discount codes that users may use. However, users should also be able register uses of "private" discount codes.

In their simplest form, the tables may look something like this, with corresponding `@Entity` classes:

**discount_usages**

```
╔════╦══════════════════╦═════════╦════════════╦══════════╦═════╗
║ id ║ discount_code_id ║ user_id ║ last_used  ║ num_uses ║ ... ║
╠════╬══════════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬═════╣
║  1 ║                2 ║       7 ║ 2019-05-01 ║        3 ║     ║
║  2 ║                1 ║       4 ║ 2019-07-10 ║        1 ║     ║
║  3 ║                3 ║      11 ║ 2019-05-19 ║        2 ║     ║
║  4 ║                2 ║      11 ║ 2019-05-01 ║        1 ║     ║
║  5 ║                2 ║       6 ║ 2019-07-10 ║        1 ║     ║
║  6 ║                1 ║       4 ║ 2019-05-19 ║        2 ║     ║
╚════╩══════════════════╩═════════╩════════════╩══════════╩═════╝
```

**discount_codes**

```
╔════╦═══════╦════════════════╦═════════════════╦═════╗
║ id ║ code  ║    website     ║ expiration-date ║ ... ║
╠════╬═══════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬═════╣
║  1 ║ t3fj4 ║ somestore.com  ║ 2019-12-31      ║     ║
║  2 ║ ds7do ║ otherstore.com ║ 2019-12-31      ║     ║
║  3 ║ uw7tp ║ thirdstore.com ║ 2020-03-15      ║     ║
╚════╩═══════╩════════════════╩═════════════════╩═════╝
```

**Requirements:**

**1.** I need to show users all available `discount_codes`, i.e. all public ones and all private ones they have added/used themselves. However, users should **not** be able to see codes that other users have added to their own lists.

**2.** Users should be able to register a purchase from website x during which they used code y. If it's a new `discount_code`, it should be saved. The usage should be saved to `discount_usages` as well, as a new row if it's the user's first usage of the `discount_code`, or by updating the row if the user has previously used the code.

**Notes:**

- (`discount_code_id`, `user_id`) uniquely identifies a row in `discount_usages`.
- This may also be modeled as a `@ManyToOne` relationship if each "private" `discount_code` gets saved on a separate row for each customer that uses it.

**Question:**

Is it possible meet these requirements without adding huge amounts of complexity? My first attempt was adding the following to the `DiscountCode` entity:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = true) User ownedByUser;
```

and then in `DiscountCodeRepository`:

```
@Query("select d from DiscountCode d where d.ownedByUser.id is null
        or d.ownedByUser.id = :userId")
findAllByOwnedByUserIdOrOwnedByUserIdIsNull(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

but the complexity of this increases very fast, and it's easy to make a programming error to accidentally show private codes to the wrong users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible meet these requirements without adding huge amounts of complexity?

In my opinion sure you can.

If you worry about future complexity, you could use `Specification pattern` https://www.martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf

In your case you can write these rules:

- all public ones
- all private ones they have added/used themselves

For code example see here:

https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/tree/master/specification

Comment: thanks, that looks like a good fit. Could you show an example of how this can be done in spring jpa? Based on the example code, a similar implementation would be adding `boolean isPrivate` and an optional `@ManyToOne User user` attribute to `DiscountCode`. Then fetching all `DiscountCodes` from db and filter on the added attributes with a `DiscountSelector`. That's quite a bit of duplication, but it may be worth it?

Comment: You can find example using `Spring JPA` here: https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications . Adding boolean `isPrivate` seems like a good idea. I am not sure where you see duplication? This approach generates more code but it's harder to make a programming error to accidentally show private codes to the wrong users and other similar cases.

Comment: you're right, it's not a lot of duplication, the only thing is that it could be possible to infer both both attributes based on the `discount_usages` table. But that's an insignificant drawdown; I mentioned it primarily in case you had a specific even better approach in mind :) Thanks for your help, it is much appreciated.